# Bootstrap NavBar css not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using a bootstrap navbar in my angular app.component.html but, the css is not working properly:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded header main-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-brand headerTitle" >MerchantEdge</div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link rightside-header" href="#">Aquirer Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link rightside-header" href="#">Merchant Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image: It is coming like this]

Comment: what do u need ?

Comment: @MohammadAli css is not working you can see the navbar button getting below the fixed header and the background color is transparent

Answer (score 0):

That's not the [correct Navbar markup](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) for the latest Bootstrap 4.

`navbar-toggleable-md` should be `navbar-expand-md`

`bg-faded` should be `bg-light`

There is no longer a `navbar-toggler-right` class